# Is there a way to use the condition of a ternary to be the value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I run into a lot of cases where I would like to use the condition of a ternary as the actual value of its output. Is there a way to do this without having to say the condition again?

For example:
`var thing = veryCoolThingExistsButItsNameIsVeryLong ? veryCoolThingExistsButItsNameIsVeryLong : otherThing;`

What I want is something that looks more like this:
`var thing = veryCoolThingExists?otherThing;` where `thing` is assigned `otherThing` only if `veryCoolThingExists` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the logical OR operator, `||`,

```
var thing = veryCoolThingExistsButItsNameIsVeryLong || otherThing;
```

which returns the first value if it's truthy or the second if not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that by just using the logical or `||`

`var thing = veryCoolThingExistsButItsNameIsVeryLong || otherThing;`